# Tesseract .Net 3.0.2 from NuGet failed to initialize engine

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, tesseract

I have downloaded version 3.0.2 of Tesseract from NuGet, however when I try to initialize the engine as below

```
using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(null, "eng"))
```

it just failed. The error message as below

> {Tesseract.TesseractException: Failed to initialise tesseract engine..
>   See https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/wiki/Error-1 for details.
>   at Tesseract.TesseractEngine.Initialise(String datapath, String
>   language, EngineMode engineMode, IEnumerable`1 configFiles,
>   IDictionary`2 initialValues, Boolean setOnlyNonDebugVariables)    at
>   Tesseract.TesseractEngine..ctor(String datapath, String language,
>   EngineMode engineMode, IEnumerable`1 configFiles, IDictionary`2
>   initialOptions, Boolean setOnlyNonDebugVariables)    at
>   Tesseract.TesseractEngine..ctor(String datapath, String language)
>   at
>   SuperSystemExamScrapper.frmExamScraper.webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(Object
>   sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) in
>   c:\ApplyIT\Projects\SEDUG\SEDUG_WEB_APP\SourceCode\SuperSystemExamScrapper\frmExamScraper.cs:line
>   235}

Anybody knows how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Go here and read carefully. https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/wiki/Error-1

Comment: @Steve it'd be nice to have the solution here, as my company blocks `github` here :(

Comment: @Alisson Maybe this will help? https://archive.is/GPCnY

Comment: @Steve lol I didn't know something like this existed. That really helps me, thank you!